# set operation on a property return IList is not working

Tags: c#

I have an interface with:

```
IList<int> CategoryIDs {get;set;}
```

Then a class that inherits this interface:

```
public IList<int> CategoryIDs
{

     get {}  // this part works
     set { _categoryIDs = value;   // error!

}
```

The set part of the accessor reports an error:

> cannot implicity convert type `IList<int>` to `List<int>`.

What should I do? confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate and assign a List just fine with a minor tweak:

```
private IList<int> _categoryIDs; // use IList instead of List
public IList<int> CategoryIDs
{

     get { return _categoryIDs; }
     set { _categoryIDs = value; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

IList is an interface, List is a concrete class.  List may implement IList, but other classes may as well, so you cannot assign an IList to a List without a cast.  Try something like this instead:

```
private IList<int> _list = new List();
public IList<int> List
{
    get { return _list; }
    set { _list = value; }
}
```

Of course, you should not be writing code in your class that assumes that List or _list is actually a list, you should be treating it generically as an IList.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) It's usually a bad idea to put a setter on an `IList<T>` member.  You typically want people to work on your existing list, but not replace it completely.  This would look like:

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    IList<int> CategoryIDs {get;} // Only put get
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
     List<int> categoryIDs;

     public IList<int> CategoryIDs
     {
          get { return this.categoryIDs; }
     }
}
```

2) If you do need to do that, you'll have to either cast the `IList<T>` to a `List<T>` in order to set it, or make a copy.

```
public interface IMyInterface {
    IList<int> CategoryIDs {get;set;} 
}

public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
     List<int> categoryIDs;

     public IList<int> CategoryIDs
     {
          get { return this.categoryIDs; }
          set
          {
                List<int> asList = value as List<int>;
                if (asList != null)
                    this.categoryIDs = asList;
                else
                    this.categoryIDs = new List<int>(value); // Copy values across into new list!
          }
     }
}
```

Either way, this approach is a bit "clunky" feeling.

Comment: problem is I am using .AddRange in my getter, so I have to use a List or change my code :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your field `_categoryIDs` is declared as `List<T>`, while your property is `IList<T>` (or even `IList`, it's hard to say with broken source code formatting in the question). `IList<T>` (and `IList`) is an interface; `List<T>` is a class implementing that interface. Because of that, you can assign `List` reference to variable of type `IList`, but not vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Your set function is missing the second bracket.